# Use Graphileon InterActor on different Neo4j databases

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphileon

I installed Graphileon in Windows using Docker. In Graphileon InterActor users can be added and deleted by using Cypher. But when I want to switch databases and give neo4j the path to another '.graphdb-folder' all the users and functions from InterActor disappear. I cant even log in to InterActor. So it only works with the default DB.

Can I simply copy some files to another .graphdb-folder and use Graphileon on it (if possible with my old settings and styles) ? Neo4j works perfectly for all db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Docker version of InterActor (that's the name of the product) is a Community Version, only meant to run against a single Neo4j store, and no possibilities to separate InterActor users/ Functions from your business data. The InterActor Enterprise version has these kind of capabilities. 
If you want to try out InterActor against multiple stores to study different usecases, I advise to use the Sandbox https://interactor.graphileon.com/sandbox/signup.html , of which you're can create create n copies :)

**Disclaimer**  I am the owner of Graphileon.